Accessing a printer from another site (on another network)
My (small) company has two sites that have different networks, let's call them Main Site and Satellite Site. To access the company's main network at the Main Site, a user at the Satellite connects from a small local PC to a powerful PC at the Main Site. Unfortunately due to a rural location, our bandwidth at the Main Site is fairly limited (~30 Mbps down / 3 Mbps up).
We have started using Parsec thanks to how well it performs wrt low-latency even with a slow internet service. Previously we were using a VPN connected to a VM on the Main Site network, but it was so slow that it was pratically unusable.
Anyway, on to the crux of the issue... There is a MFP printer connected to the local network at the Satellite Site which the user would like to use to print things from the Main Site PC. When we used the VPN, the local (Satellite) printer could be used from the Main Site VM. With Parsec this is (of course) no longer possible.
What is the best solution to allow the printer at the Satellite Site to be accessible to the PCs on both sites?

Printing uses port 9100. If you open that port on the router, you can locally create a printer with the WAN ip of main site and the port you specify in the router to connect to the external printer, and then specify the correct driver. Another option is to create a VPN tunnel between both sites to join both networks. (preferred option)

"our bandwidth at the Main Site is fairly limited (~30 Mbps down / 3 Mbps up)" – that is relatively speaking a very decent amount of bandwidth for work. (I routinely use RDP over that kind of connection and it's practically seamless...) The question though is what latency do you have between your sites total, as well as from the second site to its ISP? What WAN technology does the site use? And what is the physical distance between the two?

@grawity_u1686 While the physical distance isn't far (4 km), I work for an architecture company and there is a lot of data being transmitted when someone wants to use a CAD program. When I said the VPN was so slow that it was practically unusable, I wasn't speaking anecdotally - it really is extremely slow, even with a powerful client PC. We've only been testing Parsec for a few days but it is noticeably faster - almost unbelievably so. The only thing missing is printer support.

What remote control software were you using over the VPN – Windows RDP? VNC? Teamviewer? "VPN" is a network connection, not a remote control connection, so although it may be slow in general, it doesn't make sense to talk about a VPN being slow in comparison to Parsec; that's very much an "apples to oranges" kind of thing.

@grawity_u1686 We were using Lancom VPN to connect directly to the main network.
